# Magento ver. 1.8.0.0, unable to install rwd/default responsive theme

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, install, rwd, rwd-theme

I am trying to install the latest rwd/default theme onto my live server magento installed on GoDaddy hosting. Version of the magento installed on GoDaddy is `1.8.0.0` whereas on my localhost the version is `1.9.0.1`.

I have tried all the steps as listed on magento commerce website like created directories (`customtheme/custompackage/etc`), copying the files from rwd/default to `customtheme/custompackage`, then adding the same in Magento backend `System/Configuration/Design`.

But my live Magento server is picking the default theme instead of the `rwd/default` or customtheme.

Answer (score 2):

The directory structure `rwd/default` is the theme/package so you should just have to drop them into the `skin/frontend` directory. Then find the JS files for the RWD theme and move them over to the same directory structure.

Comment: Thanks!But rwd/default folder is already there in skin/frontend directory. I have tried changing the design in magento backend but no success. Should i try and add a custom folder theme and copy the the contents of rwd/default folder to the custom folder and then do the design changes in magento backend. Pls advise

Comment: You could but it seems like you don't have the rwd/default setup properly in the first place so it is doubtful you'd get another one setup properly. The best I could do is point you to [Magento Theme Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes)

Comment: I have tried the above mentioned process (created a folder 'custom' on skin/frontend directory and app/design/frontend/ directory). Keeping the contents of custom theme folder same as rwd theme, i applied the custom theme on localhost machine and it worked. But when i applied the same method on my FTP server, there were some noticeable changes. My server homepage doesn't changed but all the other pages have picked up the correct theme i.e. 'custom'. But my homepage and the layout of all other pages has not changed.

Comment: Plus, under the CMS>Pages tab, i am having different pages on my localhost and FTerver. How should i resolve this.P s